# Class 'ZipArchive' not found

Tags: php, linux, rhel, phpspreadsheet

#### What I want to realize

I will use [PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) in a PHP web application development,
I am trying to configure PHP Zip extension necessary for PhpSpreadsheet to be enabled on the server.
I tried two methods, but I could not set it well, so I would like you to tell me the solution and other things to check.

#### 1st method I tried

Execute the following at the terminal

```
# yum install php71-php-pecl-zip.x86_64
# cp /etc/opt/remi/php71/php.d/40-zip.ini /etc/php.d/40-zip.ini
# systemctl stop httpd.service
# systemctl start httpd.service
```

When executing processing using PhpSpreadsheet from the Web browser, an error occurred

```
/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php: 71
Class 'ZipArchive' not found
```

I confirmed that the Zip extension is enabled at the terminal, but I do not know the cause.

```
# php --info
Additional. Ini files parsed =>
·
·
/etc/php.d/40-zip.ini
·
·
zip

Zip => enabled
Zip version => 1.15.2
Libzip headers version => 1.3.2
Libzip library version => 1.5.1

zlib

ZLib Support => enabled
Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib: / /
Stream Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version => 1.2.7
Linked Version => 1.2.7

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
zlib.output_compression => Off => Off
zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
zlib.output_handler => no value => no value

# php vendor / phpoffice / phpspreadsheet / samples / index.php
Requirement check:
PHP 5.6.0 ... passed
PHP extension XML ... passed
PHP extension xmlwriter ... passed
PHP extension mbstring ... passed
PHP extension ZipArchive ... passed
PHP extension GD (optional) ... passed
PHP extension dom (optional) ... passed
```

#### 2nd method I tried

After canceling the setting of 1st (uninstall package, delete the copied file)
Execute the following at the terminal

```
# yum install php71-php-devel.x86_64
# yum install zlib-devel.x86_64
# pecl install zip
```

The following error occurred in the third command

```
# pecl install zip
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/zip"
install failed
```

Due to the error above, downloading the file and executing `phpize` will not proceed with an error again ...

```
# wget http://pecl.php.net/get/zip-1.15.2.tgz
# phpize
Can not find PHP headers in /usr/include/php
The php-devel package is required for use of this command.
```

I did not understand why errors occurred in `pecl install zip` and`phpize`.

#### Additional information (FW / tool version, etc.)

OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)

PHP: 7.1.14

Answer (score 3):

first, run this command

```
sudo yum install php-zip
```

after change php.ini file

```
extension=zip.so
```

now run this command.

```
sudo service httpd restart
sudo service php-fpm restart
```

it's working for me in cent os on amazon server.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for CentOS 8:

```
yum install php74-libzip.x86_64
yum install php-pecl-zip
```

Answer (score 0):

For the [ZipArchive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class to be present, PHP needs to have the [zip extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) installed.

See [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php) for installation instructions (both Linux and Windows).

Comment: I tried using `phpize` by referring to **Installation via PECL**, but it did not work.
Is there something else I can try without reinstalling PHP?